# Server state and users in a Meteor app, how to create state?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have a Meteor application where I use RiveScript, a chatbot module for Node. The module can save some aspects of user input. My issue is that when I run the module on server, the state is not saved for one user, but for all users. How would I go about creating a state for each user?

One method would be to create a new bot for each user like so:

```
let RiveScript = require('rivescript');
let users = {};
Meteor.onConnection(connection => {
    users[connection.id] = new RiveScript({utf8: true});
    users[connection.id].bot.loadDirectory('directory/',
        () => {
            users[connection.id].bot.sortReplies();
        }
    );
    connection.onClose(() => {
        delete users[connection.id]
    })
});
```

However, in terms of memory management this can cause an issue. Are there any commonly used patterns in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Meteor nor RiveScript, so I hope I'm answering your question.

If you want to keep a certain state for each conversation, e.g.

- Chat #1 : the bot is waiting for the user to answer a particular question
- Chat #2 : the bot is waiting for a command
- ...

Why don't you use a simple array mapping a conversation identifier (or in your case `connection.id`, I'm guessing) to its current state?

Example:

```
// Just to simulate an enumeration
var States = {WAITING: 0, WAITING_XXX_CONFIRMATION: 1, ...}


var state = [];

Meteor.onConnection(connection => {
    state[connection.id] =  States.WAITING;

});

// Somewhere else, e.g. in response to a command
    if (state[connection.id] == WAITING_XXX_CONFIRMATION && input === 'yes') {
        // do something

       // reset the state
       set[connection.id] = WAITING;
    }
```

You could then keep track of the state of every conversation, and act accordingly. You could also wrap the state management inside an object to make it more reusable and nice to use (e.g. `StateManager`, to be able to make calls such as `StateManager.of(chatId).set(newState)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The state is handled by the RiveScript object, and I can't explicitly handle the state outside that object by some other method. I don't think I fully grasp your suggestion?